# Cusp form growth condition

Tags: fourier-series, modular-forms

Zagier gives an equivalent definition of a cusp form, being a modular form with Fourier expansion
$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)e^{2\pi i n z}$ with $a(0)=0$. This is apparently equivalent to $|f(z)|<M\Im(z)^{-k/2}$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$. I see that if $|f(z)|<M\Im(z)^{-k/2}$ then we must have $a(0)=0$ since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)e^{2\pi i n z}$ vanishes as $\Im(z)\rightarrow\infty$. But I don't see why the reverse implication holds. We'd need to bound the $a(n)$?

Comment: Hint: if $f(z)$ is invariant in weight $k$ for a certain congruence group $\Gamma$ (eg $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$), then $|f(z)|y^{k/2}$ is invariant (as a function, ie in weight $0$) under $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Mindlack I think I've figured it out. Assuming $a(0)=0$ we have $|f(z)|=O(e^{-2\pi y})$ (as $y=\Im(z)\rightarrow \infty)$. So $\phi(z)\rightarrow 0$ as $\Im(z)\rightarrow\infty$. It is also continuous which implies (?) that is is bounded everywhere as required. Not sure where to use that $\phi(z)$ is weight zero modular though...

Comment: @Mindlack Actually, thinking about it, I suppose you would want to appeal to the fact that $\phi(\gamma z)=\phi(z)$ to justify that $\phi(z)$ continuous $\implies$ $\phi(z)$ bounded.

Comment: indeed, your first comment completely solves the problem. I was thinking too much about “bounding $a_n$” (which requires using this $\phi$ and then finding the correct y-coordinate to compute the $n$-th coefficient) and not enough about the actual question.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it enough to say that $\phi$ is continuous and bounded as $\Im(z)\rightarrow\infty$ to conclude that it's bounded everywhere? Could it be unbounded near $0$?

Comment: It depends. Is your congruence subgroup $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$? If so, yes, because the $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-orbit of any point in the hyperplane contains a point $z$ such that $|z| \geq 1$ and $|\Re{z} |\leq 1/2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131190/discussion-between-jshpmm-and-mindlack).